# SQL1032N No start database manager command was issued. SQLSTATE=57019

Tags: docker, db2, tivoli

I have a DB2 and TDS installation on docker instance, when I try to start my TDS instance I get the following error

```
GLPSRV200I Initializing primary database and its connections.
GLPRDB001E Error code -1 from function:" SQLConnect " ldapdb2b .
12/11/2017 10:51:34     0   0   SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.
SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019
GLPRDB004E The directory server is unable to connect to the database.
GLPSRV064E Failed to initialize be_config.
GLPSRV040E Server starting in configuration only mode due to errors.
```

Digging deeper, I accessed the logs on instance owner home /home/dsrdbm01/idsslapd-dsrdbm01/logs/ and tailed the db2cli.log to find the following:

```
2017-12-11-10:50:32.native retcode = -1032; state = "57019"; message = "SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019"
2017-12-11-10:50:32native retcode = -1032; state = "08001"; message = "[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.`  SQLSTATE=57019
```

I figured that I needed to start the DB manager using the db2start command, so I access the db2 bin from the installation folder on /opt/IBM/db2/V9.7/bin/, SU'ed as instance owner and then typed db2start to get the following:

```
[dsrdbm01@b4aa75a27ceb bin]$ db2start
12/11/2017 11:03:11     0   0   SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.
SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019
```

Below are the system details:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

**EDIT:**
Running DB2Diag I got the result below:

```html
[dsrdbm01@b4aa75a27ceb bin]$ db2diag
2017-12-11-10.31.48.646655+000 I1E1587             LEVEL: Event
PID     : 233                  TID  : 140078263629696PROC : db2diag
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, RAS/PD component, pdLogInternal, probe:120
START   : New Diagnostic Log file
DATA #1 : Build Level, 152 bytes
Instance "dsrdbm01" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL09078"
with level identifier "08090107".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v9.7.0.8", "s130316", "IP23433", Fix Pack "8".
DATA #2 : System Info, 440 bytes
System: Linux b4aa75a27ceb 9 4 x86_64
CPU: total:2 online:2 Cores per socket:2 Threading degree per core:1
Physical Memory(MB): total:2986 free:1516
Virtual  Memory(MB): total:4010 free:2540
Swap     Memory(MB): total:1024 free:1024
Kernel   Params: msgMaxMessageSize:8192 msgMsgMap:16384 msgMaxQueueIDs:32000
                 msgNumberOfHeaders:16384 msgMaxQueueSize:16384
                 msgMaxSegmentSize:16 shmMax:9223372036854775807 shmMin:1
                 shmIDs:4096 shmSegments:4096 semMap:1024000000 semIDs:32000
                 semNum:1024000000 semUndo:1024000000 semNumPerID:32000
                 semOps:500 semUndoSize:20 semMaxVal:32767
                 semAdjustOnExit:32767
Cur cpu time limit (seconds)  = 0xFFFFFFFF
Cur file size limit (bytes) = 0xFFFFFFFF
Cur data size (bytes)  = 0xFFFFFFFF
Cur stack size (bytes)  = 0x00800000
Cur core size (bytes)  = 0x00000000
Cur memory size (bytes) = 0xFFFFFFFF
nofiles (descriptors)  = 0x00100000

Information in this record is only valid at the time when this file was
created (see this record's time stamp)

2017-12-11-10.31.48.646503+000 I1589E372           LEVEL: Event
PID     : 233                  TID  : 140078263629696PROC : db2diag
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, RAS/PD component, pdDiagArchiveDiagnosticLog, probe:88
CREATE  : DB2DIAG.LOG ARCHIVE : /home/dsrdbm01/sqllib/db2dump/db2diag.log_2017-12-11-10.31.48 : success
IMPACT  : Potential

2017-12-11-10.38.30.442137+000 I1962E305           LEVEL: Event
PID     : 391                  TID  : 140260437010304PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleIssueStartStop, probe:21
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Single node instance [0] is starting

2017-12-11-10.38.30.442475+000 I2268E1637          LEVEL: Event
PID     : 391                  TID  : 140260437010304PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleStartStopSingleNode, probe:1130
DATA #1 : String, 34 bytes
/home/dsrdbm01/sqllib/adm/db2star2
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 256 bytes
0x00007FFD5C9E48A0 : 2F68 6F6D 652F 6473 7264 626D 3031 2F73    /home/dsrdbm01/s
0x00007FFD5C9E48B0 : 716C 6C69 622F 6164 6D2F 6462 3273 7461    qllib/adm/db2sta
0x00007FFD5C9E48C0 : 7232 004E 4F4D 5347 0000 0000 0000 0000    r2.NOMSG........
0x00007FFD5C9E48D0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E48E0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E48F0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E4900 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E4910 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E4920 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E4930 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E4940 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E4950 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E4960 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E4970 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E4980 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD5C9E4990 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................

2017-12-11-10.38.31.183758+000 E3906E314           LEVEL: Info
PID     : 393                  TID  : 140301791545216PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloKADetermineKernelIntegrity, probe:30
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Indeterminable operating system.

2017-12-11-10.38.31.184024+000 E4221E272           LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 393                  TID  : 140301791545216PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloKAAnalyze, probe:10
DATA #1 : Codepath, 8 bytes
5

2017-12-11-10.39.31.199729+000 E4494E1535          LEVEL: Severe (OS)
PID     : 393                  TID  : 140301791545216PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloWaitIPCWaitPost, probe:100
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8300002A=-2097151958
CALLED  : OS, -, msgrcv                           OSERR: ENOMSG (42)
DATA #1 : timeout value, 4 bytes
0
DATA #2 : String, 218 bytes
{
   pc    = 0x0
   cs    = {
   lock          = { 0x01 [ locked ] }
   fighterCount  = 0
   identity      = sqlo_waitpost::cs (6)
}

   state = 0x2 ((Empty))
   guard = initialized
   flags = 0x2
   numWaiters  = 1
}
DATA #3 : ipc waitpost, PD_TYPE_SQLO_IPCWAITPOST, 24 bytes
0x00000002004800C8 : 0000 0000 0100 0600 0200 0000 FEAB 0000    ................
0x00000002004800D8 : 0200 0000 0100 0000                        ........
DATA #4 : system V message queue identifier., PD_TYPE_SYSV_QUEUE_ID, 4 bytes
0x000F0001
DATA #5 : Bitmask, 8 bytes
0x0000000000000000
CALLSTCK: (Static functions may not be resolved correctly, as they are resolved to the nearest symbol)
  [0] 0x00007F9A8A743817 pdLogSysRC + 0x22B
  [1] 0x00007F9A8A1BE994 sqloWaitIPCWaitPost + 0x38A
  [2] 0x000000000040B941 DB2StartMain + 0x4EB5
  [3] 0x0000000000406A7F main + 0x37
  [4] 0x00007F9A86FDBB35 __libc_start_main + 0xF5
  [5] 0x00000000004069B9 __gxx_personality_v0 + 0x2F1
  [6] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [7] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [8] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [9] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0

2017-12-11-10.39.31.200902+000 I6030E382           LEVEL: Error
PID     : 393                  TID  : 140301791545216PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, DB2StartMain, probe:660
MESSAGE : db2sysc exited prematurely. sqlcode :
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007FFD499FC48C : 2A00 0083                                  *...

2017-12-11-10.39.31.200968+000 I6413E357           LEVEL: Error
PID     : 393                  TID  : 140301791545216PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, DB2StartMain, probe:670
MESSAGE : db2syscPID :
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007FFD499F59C8 : 8B01 0000                                  ....

2017-12-11-10.39.31.426658+000 I6771E298           LEVEL: Event
PID     : 391                  TID  : 140260437010304PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleIssueStartStop, probe:190
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Single node stopped [-1032].

2017-12-11-10.49.31.798432+000 I7070E305           LEVEL: Event
PID     : 499                  TID  : 139691711887232PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleIssueStartStop, probe:21
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Single node instance [0] is starting

2017-12-11-10.49.31.798804+000 I7376E1637          LEVEL: Event
PID     : 499                  TID  : 139691711887232PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleStartStopSingleNode, probe:1130
DATA #1 : String, 34 bytes
/home/dsrdbm01/sqllib/adm/db2star2
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 256 bytes
0x00007FFE7FB3FED0 : 2F68 6F6D 652F 6473 7264 626D 3031 2F73    /home/dsrdbm01/s
0x00007FFE7FB3FEE0 : 716C 6C69 622F 6164 6D2F 6462 3273 7461    qllib/adm/db2sta
0x00007FFE7FB3FEF0 : 7232 004E 4F4D 5347 0000 0000 0000 0000    r2.NOMSG........
0x00007FFE7FB3FF00 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FF10 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FF20 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FF30 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FF40 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FF50 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FF60 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FF70 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FF80 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FF90 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FFA0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FFB0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFE7FB3FFC0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................

2017-12-11-10.49.32.563312+000 E9014E314           LEVEL: Info
PID     : 501                  TID  : 140003416967040PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloKADetermineKernelIntegrity, probe:30
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Indeterminable operating system.

2017-12-11-10.49.32.563603+000 E9329E272           LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 501                  TID  : 140003416967040PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloKAAnalyze, probe:10
DATA #1 : Codepath, 8 bytes
5

2017-12-11-10.50.32.581305+000 E9602E1535          LEVEL: Severe (OS)
PID     : 501                  TID  : 140003416967040PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloWaitIPCWaitPost, probe:100
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8300002A=-2097151958
CALLED  : OS, -, msgrcv                           OSERR: ENOMSG (42)
DATA #1 : timeout value, 4 bytes
0
DATA #2 : String, 218 bytes
{
   pc    = 0x0
   cs    = {
   lock          = { 0x01 [ locked ] }
   fighterCount  = 0
   identity      = sqlo_waitpost::cs (6)
}

   state = 0x2 ((Empty))
   guard = initialized
   flags = 0x2
   numWaiters  = 1
}
DATA #3 : ipc waitpost, PD_TYPE_SQLO_IPCWAITPOST, 24 bytes
0x00000002004800C8 : 0000 0000 0100 0600 0200 0000 FEAB 0000    ................
0x00000002004800D8 : 0200 0000 0100 0000                        ........
DATA #4 : system V message queue identifier., PD_TYPE_SYSV_QUEUE_ID, 4 bytes
0x00128002
DATA #5 : Bitmask, 8 bytes
0x0000000000000000
CALLSTCK: (Static functions may not be resolved correctly, as they are resolved to the nearest symbol)
  [0] 0x00007F5511F17817 pdLogSysRC + 0x22B
  [1] 0x00007F5511992994 sqloWaitIPCWaitPost + 0x38A
  [2] 0x000000000040B941 DB2StartMain + 0x4EB5
  [3] 0x0000000000406A7F main + 0x37
  [4] 0x00007F550E7AFB35 __libc_start_main + 0xF5
  [5] 0x00000000004069B9 __gxx_personality_v0 + 0x2F1
  [6] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [7] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [8] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [9] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0

2017-12-11-10.50.32.583379+000 I11138E382          LEVEL: Error
PID     : 501                  TID  : 140003416967040PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, DB2StartMain, probe:660
MESSAGE : db2sysc exited prematurely. sqlcode :
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007FFF5F895A5C : 2A00 0083                                  *...

2017-12-11-10.50.32.583502+000 I11521E357          LEVEL: Error
PID     : 501                  TID  : 140003416967040PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, DB2StartMain, probe:670
MESSAGE : db2syscPID :
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007FFF5F88EF98 : F701 0000                                  ....

2017-12-11-10.50.32.757055+000 I11879E298          LEVEL: Event
PID     : 499                  TID  : 139691711887232PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleIssueStartStop, probe:190
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Single node stopped [-1032].

2017-12-11-10.50.33.411733+000 I12178E305          LEVEL: Event
PID     : 505                  TID  : 139741130913664PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleIssueStartStop, probe:21
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Single node instance [0] is starting

2017-12-11-10.50.33.412077+000 I12484E1637         LEVEL: Event
PID     : 505                  TID  : 139741130913664PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleStartStopSingleNode, probe:1130
DATA #1 : String, 34 bytes
/home/dsrdbm01/sqllib/adm/db2star2
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 256 bytes
0x00007FFD923FBA00 : 2F68 6F6D 652F 6473 7264 626D 3031 2F73    /home/dsrdbm01/s
0x00007FFD923FBA10 : 716C 6C69 622F 6164 6D2F 6462 3273 7461    qllib/adm/db2sta
0x00007FFD923FBA20 : 7232 004E 4F4D 5347 0000 0000 0000 0000    r2.NOMSG........
0x00007FFD923FBA30 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBA40 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBA50 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBA60 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBA70 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBA80 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBA90 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBAA0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBAB0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBAC0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBAD0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBAE0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD923FBAF0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................

2017-12-11-10.50.34.014886+000 E14122E314          LEVEL: Info
PID     : 507                  TID  : 139859105171328PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloKADetermineKernelIntegrity, probe:30
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Indeterminable operating system.

2017-12-11-10.50.34.015146+000 E14437E272          LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 507                  TID  : 139859105171328PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloKAAnalyze, probe:10
DATA #1 : Codepath, 8 bytes
5

2017-12-11-10.51.34.032125+000 E14710E1535         LEVEL: Severe (OS)
PID     : 507                  TID  : 139859105171328PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloWaitIPCWaitPost, probe:100
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8300002A=-2097151958
CALLED  : OS, -, msgrcv                           OSERR: ENOMSG (42)
DATA #1 : timeout value, 4 bytes
0
DATA #2 : String, 218 bytes
{
   pc    = 0x0
   cs    = {
   lock          = { 0x01 [ locked ] }
   fighterCount  = 0
   identity      = sqlo_waitpost::cs (6)
}

   state = 0x2 ((Empty))
   guard = initialized
   flags = 0x2
   numWaiters  = 1
}
DATA #3 : ipc waitpost, PD_TYPE_SQLO_IPCWAITPOST, 24 bytes
0x00000002004800C8 : 0000 0000 0100 0600 0200 0000 FEAB 0000    ................
0x00000002004800D8 : 0200 0000 0100 0000                        ........
DATA #4 : system V message queue identifier., PD_TYPE_SYSV_QUEUE_ID, 4 bytes
0x00158001
DATA #5 : Bitmask, 8 bytes
0x0000000000000000
CALLSTCK: (Static functions may not be resolved correctly, as they are resolved to the nearest symbol)
  [0] 0x00007F33784A3817 pdLogSysRC + 0x22B
  [1] 0x00007F3377F1E994 sqloWaitIPCWaitPost + 0x38A
  [2] 0x000000000040B941 DB2StartMain + 0x4EB5
  [3] 0x0000000000406A7F main + 0x37
  [4] 0x00007F3374D3BB35 __libc_start_main + 0xF5
  [5] 0x00000000004069B9 __gxx_personality_v0 + 0x2F1
  [6] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [7] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [8] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [9] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0

2017-12-11-10.51.34.033328+000 I16246E382          LEVEL: Error
PID     : 507                  TID  : 139859105171328PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, DB2StartMain, probe:660
MESSAGE : db2sysc exited prematurely. sqlcode :
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007FFD63F3226C : 2A00 0083                                  *...

2017-12-11-10.51.34.033412+000 I16629E357          LEVEL: Error
PID     : 507                  TID  : 139859105171328PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, DB2StartMain, probe:670
MESSAGE : db2syscPID :
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007FFD63F2B7A8 : FD01 0000                                  ....

2017-12-11-10.51.34.154540+000 I16987E298          LEVEL: Event
PID     : 505                  TID  : 139741130913664PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleIssueStartStop, probe:190
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Single node stopped [-1032].

2017-12-11-11.02.10.623731+000 I17286E305          LEVEL: Event
PID     : 668                  TID  : 140339545905024PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleIssueStartStop, probe:21
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Single node instance [0] is starting

2017-12-11-11.02.10.624075+000 I17592E1637         LEVEL: Event
PID     : 668                  TID  : 140339545905024PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleStartStopSingleNode, probe:1130
DATA #1 : String, 34 bytes
/home/dsrdbm01/sqllib/adm/db2star2
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 256 bytes
0x00007FFD4C159550 : 2F68 6F6D 652F 6473 7264 626D 3031 2F73    /home/dsrdbm01/s
0x00007FFD4C159560 : 716C 6C69 622F 6164 6D2F 6462 3273 7461    qllib/adm/db2sta
0x00007FFD4C159570 : 7232 004E 4F4D 5347 0000 0000 0000 0000    r2.NOMSG........
0x00007FFD4C159580 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C159590 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C1595A0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C1595B0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C1595C0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C1595D0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C1595E0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C1595F0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C159600 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C159610 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C159620 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C159630 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0x00007FFD4C159640 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................

2017-12-11-11.02.11.233890+000 E19230E314          LEVEL: Info
PID     : 670                  TID  : 140405063419776PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloKADetermineKernelIntegrity, probe:30
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Indeterminable operating system.

2017-12-11-11.02.11.234156+000 E19545E272          LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 670                  TID  : 140405063419776PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloKAAnalyze, probe:10
DATA #1 : Codepath, 8 bytes
5

2017-12-11-11.03.11.249381+000 E19818E1535         LEVEL: Severe (OS)
PID     : 670                  TID  : 140405063419776PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloWaitIPCWaitPost, probe:100
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8300002A=-2097151958
CALLED  : OS, -, msgrcv                           OSERR: ENOMSG (42)
DATA #1 : timeout value, 4 bytes
0
DATA #2 : String, 218 bytes
{
   pc    = 0x0
   cs    = {
   lock          = { 0x01 [ locked ] }
   fighterCount  = 0
   identity      = sqlo_waitpost::cs (6)
}

   state = 0x2 ((Empty))
   guard = initialized
   flags = 0x2
   numWaiters  = 1
}
DATA #3 : ipc waitpost, PD_TYPE_SQLO_IPCWAITPOST, 24 bytes
0x00000002004800C8 : 0000 0000 0100 0600 0200 0000 FEAB 0000    ................
0x00000002004800D8 : 0200 0000 0100 0000                        ........
DATA #4 : system V message queue identifier., PD_TYPE_SYSV_QUEUE_ID, 4 bytes
0x00188001
DATA #5 : Bitmask, 8 bytes
0x0000000000000000
CALLSTCK: (Static functions may not be resolved correctly, as they are resolved to the nearest symbol)
  [0] 0x00007FB295EFF817 pdLogSysRC + 0x22B
  [1] 0x00007FB29597A994 sqloWaitIPCWaitPost + 0x38A
  [2] 0x000000000040B941 DB2StartMain + 0x4EB5
  [3] 0x0000000000406A7F main + 0x37
  [4] 0x00007FB292797B35 __libc_start_main + 0xF5
  [5] 0x00000000004069B9 __gxx_personality_v0 + 0x2F1
  [6] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [7] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [8] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0
  [9] 0x0000000000000000 ?unknown + 0x0

2017-12-11-11.03.11.250573+000 I21354E382          LEVEL: Error
PID     : 670                  TID  : 140405063419776PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, DB2StartMain, probe:660
MESSAGE : db2sysc exited prematurely. sqlcode :
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007FFE298F2E3C : 2A00 0083                                  *...

2017-12-11-11.03.11.250640+000 I21737E357          LEVEL: Error
PID     : 670                  TID  : 140405063419776PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, DB2StartMain, probe:670
MESSAGE : db2syscPID :
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007FFE298EC378 : A002 0000                                  ....

2017-12-11-11.03.11.402047+000 I22095E298          LEVEL: Event
PID     : 668                  TID  : 140339545905024PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: dsrdbm01             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleIssueStartStop, probe:190
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Single node stopped [-1032].

db2diag invoked with the default set of filtering/formatting options
on file "/opt/IBM/db2/V9.7/bin/db2diag.log".
Enter "db2diag -h" to get a short description of all available options.
```

Now I am in a closed loop, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Db2 instance is unable to start. Edit the question to append what goes into db2diag.log when you run db2start, and specify the operating-system version/release where the db2start runs

Comment: @mao I had included the updates requested

Comment: Did you get the container from IBM, or is it your own attempt to dockerize Db2? The latter is not a trivial task.

Comment: Already dokckerized it and it was working well until the license issue happened

Comment: @Mao Hence I am posting my question on StackOverflow and not IBM's DB2 Forums.

Comment: Unfortunately I too have run into the identically described problem.  Also trying to build a dockerized DB2.

Comment: Oooh ... I had a breakthrough.   Adding --privileged onto the docker run command allowed my DB2 to start.

Comment: @kolban this worked for me too, for some reason the db2 needs to change kernel flags in order to be installed correctly, which is not exposed unless you add the privileged flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On UNIX operating systems, after allocating the initial database memory size on database activation, DB2 allocates additional memory as needed to support dynamic requirements.

DB2 has a problem where it needs more shared memory than Docker originally provides, and hence the problem above happens

To solve this, DB2 needs to run in docker under what is called "Privileged Mode". Docker support site defines it as follows

> The --privileged flag gives all capabilities to the container, and it
>   also lifts all the limitations enforced by the device cgroup
>   controller. In other words, the container can then do almost
>   everything that the host can do. This flag exists to allow special
>   use-cases, like running Docker within Docker.

To resolve the error above, you need to run the container in privileged mode, that is:

```
$ docker run --privileged=true ...
```

This will increase the max shared memory size, and consequently resolves the whole situation.